# Get-PnPAzureADUser : Code: Request_UnsupportedQuery

Tags: powershell, azure-powershell

I have this weird behavior inside my PnP Power Shell:-

now if i write this Power Shell i will get results:-

```
Get-PnPAzureADUser -Filter  {AccountEnabled eq true and Mail  eq 'test@test.com'}
```

but if i define the Mail inside a variable i will get this error:-

```
PS C:\windows\system32> $rrr = "test@test.com"
PS C:\windows\system32> Get-PnPAzureADUser -Filter  {AccountEnabled eq true and Mail  eq $rrr}                          
Get-PnPAzureADUser : Code: Request_UnsupportedQuery
Message: Unsupported Query.
Inner error:
        AdditionalData:
        date: 2022-12-28T22:13:33
        request-id: 3f8d45ef-ab8e-49c9-bf6e-41e4a56c11e3
        client-request-id: 3f8d45ef-ab8e-49c9-bf6e-41e4a56c11e3
ClientRequestId: 3f8d45ef-ab8e-49c9-bf6e-41e4a56c11e3
At line:1 char:1
+ Get-PnPAzureADUser -Filter  {AccountEnabled eq true and Mail  eq $rrr ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [Get-PnPAzureADUser], PSInvalidOperationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvalidOperation,PnP.PowerShell.Commands.Principals.GetAzureADUser
```

Or this

```
PS C:\windows\system32> $rrr = "'test@test.com'"
PS C:\windows\system32> Get-PnPAzureADUser -Filter  {AccountEnabled eq true and Mail  eq $rrr}                          
Get-PnPAzureADUser : Code: Request_UnsupportedQuery
Message: Unsupported Query.
Inner error:
        AdditionalData:
        date: 2022-12-28T22:13:33
        request-id: 3f8d45ef-ab8e-49c9-bf6e-41e4a56c11e3
        client-request-id: 3f8d45ef-ab8e-49c9-bf6e-41e4a56c11e3
ClientRequestId: 3f8d45ef-ab8e-49c9-bf6e-41e4a56c11e3
At line:1 char:1
+ Get-PnPAzureADUser -Filter  {AccountEnabled eq true and Mail  eq $rrr ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [Get-PnPAzureADUser], PSInvalidOperationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvalidOperation,PnP.PowerShell.Commands.Principals.GetAzureADUser
```

Any advice? how i can pass the Mail as a variable inside the `Get-PnPAzureADUser`??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a [expandable string](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_quoting_rules?view=powershell-7.3) instead of a [script block](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_script_blocks?view=powershell-7.2) to formulate your filter:

```bash
$rrr = "test@test.com"
Get-PnPAzureADUser -Filter "AccountEnabled eq true and Mail eq '$rrr'"
```